# Terraform Postgresql provider error for AWS RDS: "dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused"

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

I have a running Terraform infrastructure which configures an `Aurora-postgresql` Serverless RDS database. Also it uses `postgresql provider` to configure the database roles, for example using `postgresql_role` resource and others.

I need to destroy this RDS serverless DB and replace it with a provisioned one.

I have updated the TF `aws_rds_cluster` resource and when trying to deploy it with my new `provisioned` config using `terraform apply`, I get the following errors for the `postgresql provider` resources (which are unchanged):

```
Error: could not start transaction: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused
│ 
│   with postgresql_database.testdb,
│   on main.aws.db.tf line 54, in resource "postgresql_database" "testdb":
│   54: resource "postgresql_database" "testdb" {
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused
│ 
│   with postgresql_role.materialized_view_owner,
│   on main.aws.db.tf line 62, in resource "postgresql_role" "materialized_view_owner":
│   62: resource "postgresql_role" "materialized_view_owner" {
```

This seems to indicate the provider is not able to connect to the database or uses incorrect endpoint. Yet the serverless database is running and the provider is configured to use it's endpoint as the `host`. At the moment the errors appear, Terraform has not yet seen the `aws_rds_cluster` change from serverless to provisioned.

Provider config below:

```
provider "postgresql" {
  host      = aws_rds_cluster.postgresql.endpoint
  port      = 5432
  database  = aws_rds_cluster.postgresql.database_name
  username  = aws_rds_cluster.postgresql.master_username
  password  = aws_rds_cluster.postgresql.master_password
  sslmode   = "require"
  superuser = false
  expected_version = "10.18"
}
```

I don't really have any ideas what could cause this. Could someone help out? Thanks!

EDIT:
Adding resource definitions per request of @Marcin

postgresql provider resources:

```
resource "postgresql_database" "testdb" {
    name = "testdb"
}

resource "postgresql_role" "view_owner" {
  name  = "view_owner"
  login = false
}

resource "postgresql_grant" "view_owner" {
  database    = postgresql_database.testdb.name
  role        = postgresql_role.view_owner.name
  object_type = "table"
  schema      = "public"
  privileges  = ["SELECT"]
}

resource "postgresql_default_privileges" "view_owner" {
  database = postgresql_database.testdb.name
  role     = postgresql_role.view_owner.name
  schema   = "public"

  owner       = aws_rds_cluster.postgresql.master_username
  object_type = "table"
  privileges  = ["SELECT"]
}

resource "postgresql_grant_role" "view_owner_master_user" {
  role              = aws_rds_cluster.postgresql.master_username
  grant_role        = postgresql_role.view_owner.name
  with_admin_option = true
}
```

Comment: The error is about `resource "postgresql_database" "testdb"` yet you haven't showed such a resource TF code.

Comment: It sounds like you've changed the configuration of `aws_rds_cluster.postgresql` in a way that would require destroying and recreating the cluster, and so Terraform doesn't know a concrete value for `aws_rds_cluster.postgresql.endpoint` yet. I think the postgresql provider is then getting confused and interpreting the unknown endpoint as if you hadn't set an endpoint at all, and so it's defaulting to localhost.

Comment: I assume that you don't actually _intend_ to destroy and replace your database cluster, so I think the next step will be to figure out what change you've made that is causing the AWS provider to plan to replace the cluster. If this error is blocking you from seeing the plan for the cluster then you could try running `terraform plan -target=aws_rds_cluster.postgresql` to ask Terraform to stop right after planning the changes to the cluster.

Comment: If you run the command I just suggested and it shows a change you're not sure how to understand, please edit your question to include that plan output.

Comment: @robliv I think you also have to set the correct scheme in the provider configuration block: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cyrilgdn/postgresql/latest/docs#scheme.

Comment: @Marcin Hi, I've added the resource definitions to the OP.

Comment: @MartinAtkins I think you were right and the postgres provider couldn't retrieve the endpoint and defaulted to localhost. I used `terraform apply -target=aws_rds_cluster.postgresql` to deploy just the DB changes and afterwards found an issue with my config (cluster was created but I didn't realize I need to also specify separate resource for an instance). After fixing the issue the `postgresql provider` errors are gone. Will write this as answer and credit you. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I used `terraform apply -target=aws_rds_cluster.postgresql` to deploy just the DB cluster changes and afterwards found another issue with my TF RDS config. The Aurora cluster was created but I didn't realize I need to also specify a separate TF resource for an instance. After fixing that I re-ran the full TF apply without any targeting and the `postgresql provider` errors are gone.

Credit and thanks for help with debugging the issue goes to @MartinAtkins

Answer (score 0):

I got a very similar version of this error now when I had forgotten to add the postgresql provider. This is the first hit on Google so I am posting it herein case other are debugging this error:

```
Error: error detecting capabilities: error PostgreSQL version: dial tcp [::1]:5432: connect: connection refused
```

Check that you have a postgresql provider ;)